# how to track all heap allocation?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, memory, kernel

i want to track all heap allocations in our project,eg the directX's  memory allocations.i think i can do it by intercepting  function rtlheapalloc rtlheaprealloc rtlheapfree by the library detour  and track the parameters passed in,is this way correct?[detour](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [umdh.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343)

> The user-mode dump heap (UMDH) utility works with the operating system
>   to analyze Windows heap allocations for a specific process.